# How can I stop synchronization between chrome on PC and safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, safari, google-chrome

For the first time I opened iCloud on my PC. All of the bookmarks in Chrome are synchronized to Safari on my iPhone. I don't want this. And when I delete from Safari, I don't want the deletion to sync with Chrome.

How can I stop synchronization?

Another thing, how can I see how much space bookmarks, favorites take on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck Bookmarks in the iCloud control panel.

[image]

& point 2... not much at all; wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Sounds easy.  But how do you open the iCloud panel?  I don't see an iCloud app icon or menu anywhere.

Comment: Get it from http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html if you don't already have it